Mysql.Data case sensitive table name access?
Upon data access, the application throws:
An unhandled exception was thrown by the application. MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlException (0x80004005): Table 'AspNetUsers' doesn't exist
The so called table exists under the name 'aspnetusers'.
This doesn't happen on a windows machine and I'm aware of lower_case_table_names=1 but it needs database re-initializing the database. Is there any other way?
I tried renaming table names and it works but there should be an easier and more appropriate way to do this!
